# Would an atom OR its nucleus alone affect its surrounding empty space, with respect to the particles that come and go of existence within that space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I understand that the particles come and go of existence in the empty space. So, what effect could a stable particle (one that do not go out of existence in space) like an atom, or its nucleus alone, have on the formation and disappearance of those particles? Would the mass, charge or the mere presence of the atom, or its nucleus, induce some effect? If so, please explain it to a non-physicist.

Thank you,
Ravi

Comment: Particles don't pop in and out of existence in empty space.
 https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/physics-virtual-particles/

Answer (score 0):

The popularization of virtual particle-antiparticle pairs that briefly appear and disappear in a vacuum does require the existence of fields, so yes the existence of nearby stable particles is required.

Comment: Wonderful, Thank you Mr. Miller. Does this mean that, in the absence of a stable particle like atom, these virtual particles do not appear in space?

Comment: Tha is more of a philosophical  than a physics question. Without a field there is no way of observing them. Quantum physics is agnostic on the reality of unobserved entities.

Comment: I get it. Thank you Dr. Miller. Very kind of you to answer.